# How can I remove the post image hyperlink or edit it to target="_blank" when inside a protected folder?

Tags: images

I am handling hyperlinks differently and I don't need the image to also have a hyperlink of its own. But if it must-have it, at least I don't want it to replace my site. I'd prefer it opened in a different tab. Problem is, this is inside an `inc` folder which is protected by the parent theme and I cannot alter it in my child-theme by simply overwriting it. I must do it some other way in the functions.php file.

Here's the link in question

```
<figure class="post-thumbnail">
    <a class="post-thumbnail-inner alignwide" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    </a>
    <?php if ( wp_get_attachment_caption( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ) : ?>
        <figcaption class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wp_get_attachment_caption( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ); ?></figcaption>
    <?php endif; ?>
</figure><!-- .post-thumbnail -->
```